# how to keep button color

Tags: android, button, colors

What I have been trying to do is to save the state of button when it's pressed with sharedpreferences. When button is default, it's white, but when pressed, it's black. I want that button stay black even when I press back button or come back from other activities or apps. I have been struggling with this problem for a few days and this makes me feel that I'm so not good programming. Can anybody help me out there please? Here is my code.

```
fb1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
fb1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.not_pressed);
    fb1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        boolean isPressed = true;
        //boolean isPressed1 = true;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //isPressed = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("locked", false);
            fb1.setEnabled(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("locked", true));
            System.out.println("BOOL" + isPressed);
            if (!isPressed) { 
                fb1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.not_pressed);
                fr1 = 0;
                //fb1.setEnabled(false);
                //sharedPrefs.edit().putBoolean("locked", fb1.isEnabled()).commit();
            } else {
                fb1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pressed);
                fr1 = 128;
                //fb1.setEnabled(true);
                //savePreferences("locked", fb1.isEnabled());
                sharedPrefs.edit().putBoolean("locked", fb1.isEnabled()).commit();
            }
            isPressed = !isPressed;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why did you comment out the isPressed = sharedPrefs.getBoolean() call ? isPressed will always be true if you do not change its default value. Also you are only saving the state to shared preferences when your button is in the "pressed" state.

Answer (score 0):

First Create a constant class and declare a static variable in it:

```
public class Constants(){
public static boolean isPressed = false;
}
```

Now, use this static variable inside your Activity class to store the button pressed event throughout lifecycle of your app.

```
fb1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 
fb1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.not_pressed); 
fb1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
    if (!Constants.isPressed) {         //if button is not pressed it is set to white color(initially false)
            fb1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.not_pressed);
            fr1 = 0; 
            //fb1.setEnabled(false); 
            //sharedPrefs.edit().putBoolean("locked", fb1.isEnabled()).commit(); 
        } else {                        //if pressed to black
            fb1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pressed);
            fr1 = 128; 
            //fb1.setEnabled(true); 
            //savePreferences("locked", fb1.isEnabled()); 
            sharedPrefs.edit().putBoolean("locked", fb1.isEnabled()).commit(); 
        }
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //isPressed = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("locked", false); 
        fb1.setEnabled(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("locked", true)); 
        System.out.println("BOOL" + isPressed);
        Constants.isPressed = true;         //Sets is pressed to true throughout lifecycle of your app.
        //Execute other onPressed logic here
    } 
});
```

This might solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selector to select what color to display - this is example to using selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
<item
    android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/remove_contacts_button_disabled"
    />
<item
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/remove_contacts_button_highlighted"
    />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/remove_contacts_button_regular"
    />
```

In onClikLisitner save at shared preferences what you want at click.